# How can I return neighbour nodes attribute as my attrbute

Tags: memgraphdb

Take for the Game of Throne sandbox for example, I want return a list of Characters with their name, alligance if any, killed in which episode if valid, and who killed this Charater if valid. I can get alligance from LOYAL_TO relationship, and I can get killed in which episode via VICTIM_IN and HAPPENED_IN relationship, and killer name via VICTIM_IN and KILLER_IN relationship.

Can someone help me to know which capabilities I should use in Memgraph to achieve this? I can do this in neo4j via pattern match in RETURN clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we actually need is the capability of pattern comprehension capability in return cluase in neo4j 3.2 ( [What is pattern comprehension and custom projection in neo4j cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276331/what-is-pattern-comprehension-and-custom-projection-in-neo4j-cypher))

The cypher you provided during our last call works in the GoT Death scenarios, but doesn't work in our real like scenarios

```
EXPLAIN MATCH (c:Character)-[:LOYAL_TO]->(a:Allegiance) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(e:Episode),(d)<-[:KILLER_IN]-(killer:Character)
RETURN c.name AS character_name, a.name AS allegiance_name, collect(DISTINCT e.name) AS episode_names,  collect(DISTINCT killer.name) AS killer_names;
```

Because this requires both two path in OPTIONAL MATCH succeeded, and we can get additional info d,e,killer. When oen path doesn't match any thing, say if Death doesn't have a killer for data quality reason, then I can not get the episode info which actually exists.

p.s it seems that this capability of using two path in OPTIONAL MATCH has been documented yet.

Another way to solve our issue is to use MAGE neighours.at_hop capability, we are still trying to modify the source code, like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, my colleague helped me with following cypher statement, it works fine.
However, we seems to reach some performance issue on your playground. when we reach 13 OPTIONAL MATCH location, when EXPLAIN.

```
EXPLAIN MATCH (c:Character)-[:LOYAL_TO]->(a:Allegiance) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(e:Episode) 
WITH c,a,collect({name:e.name}) AS episode
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d)<-[:KILLER_IN]-(killer:Character) 
WITH c,a,episode,location,collect({name:killer.name}) as killer
RETURN c.name,a.name,episode,location,killer
```

Without EXPLAIN, 4 OPTIONAL MATCH location will hang the playground.

```
MATCH (c:Character)-[:LOYAL_TO]->(a:Allegiance) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(e:Episode) 
WITH c,a,collect({name:e.name}) AS episode
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(l:Location) 
WITH c,a,episode,collect({name:l.name}) AS location
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d)<-[:KILLER_IN]-(killer:Character) 
WITH c,a,episode,location,collect({name:killer.name}) as killer
RETURN c.name,a.name,episode,location,killer
```

[Playground hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJUZn.png)

It seems that this is something related to the contension between memory and cypher command complexixity.

Comment: I've just tried to run your query. I didn't have any issues. Can you join Memgraph Discord (https://discord.gg/memgraph)? Memgraph staff there can help you with performance issues.

Comment: We are on public holidyas now, We will set up a call when we are back. Also, I add how to reproduce this issue in the playground.

Comment: I have modified this Answer to record how to reproduce this issue,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MATCH clause](https://memgraph.com/docs/querying/clauses/match) to find data stored in the database by matching it to a given pattern. Specify node labels and properties, as well as relationship types and properties, to narrow down your search.
For your specific case with GoT dataset, you can use this query to get the names of the characters and their alliances:

```
MATCH (c:Character)-[:LOYAL_TO]->(a:Allegiance)
RETURN c.name, a.name;
```

I'm looking at the data model for [GoT dataset](https://playground.memgraph.com/sandbox/game-of-thrones-deaths), and it seems to me that each Character can be linked only to one Allegiance, so I don't know what precisely A->C->D could be in this case, but query could be something like:

```
MATCH path = (c:Character)-[:LOYAL_TO*1..2]->(a:Allegiance)
WITH c, last(relationships(path)) as rel, last(nodes(path)) as a
RETURN c.name, a.name;
```

The `MATCH` clause will attempt to match a pattern where a Character node is related to an Allegiance node through a `LOYAL_TO` relationship, with a variable length of 1 to 2 hops. Then the `WITH` clause will process the path, isolating the Character node, the last relationship in the path, and the last node (which should be an Allegiance node) in the path. This is what the `last()` function does. It gets the last element of a list, in this case, the last relationship and node in the path.

The RETURN clause then returns the names of the Character and Allegiance nodes.
This way, even if there's an intermediary node between a Character and an Allegiance, the query will still return the names of the Character and Allegiance nodes.

Comment: Thank for quick response! Let me clarify my question more precisely. Take for example, I want return a list of Characters with their name, alligance if any, killed in which episode if valid, and who killed this Charater if valid. I can get alligance from LOYAL_TO relationship, and I can get killed in which episode via VICTIM_IN and HAPPENED_IN relationship, and killer name via VICTIM_IN and KILLER_IN relationship.

Comment: @adam Wu can you please add this info to your original question?

Comment: Done， original question revised

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause. It seems that the following query would cover what you're looking for:

```
MATCH (c:Character)-[:LOYAL_TO]->(a:Allegiance) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d:Death)-[:HAPPENED_IN]->(e:Episode) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:VICTIM_IN]->(d)<-[:KILLER_IN]-(killer:Character) 
RETURN c.name AS character_name, a.name AS allegiance_name, e.name AS episode_name, killer.name AS killer_name;
```

1. The query matches `Character` nodes to `Allegiance` nodes via the `LOYAL_TO` relationship. This will give you the character's name and their allegiance.
2. It then optionally matches `Character` nodes to `Episode` nodes via the
   `VICTIM_IN` and `HAPPENED_IN` relationships. This will give you the
   episode in which the character was killed, if applicable.
3. It also optionally matches `Character` nodes to other `Character` nodes (the killers) via the `VICTIM_IN` and `KILLER_IN` relationships. This will give you the name of the character's killer, if applicable.

Comment: When I run following cypher query, I get 305 result, which seems to be right 【
  MATCH (c:Character)-[:LOYAL_TO]->(a:Allegiance) 
  RETURN c.name AS character_name, a.name AS allegiance_name 】

 However, if I run above query, I will get 2331 result, which contains duplicated data, I hope I can still get 305 result

Comment: This is because, I know people can only be killed once, so each Character can only be kiled in 0-1 season, and by 0-1 people. So I think1 OPTIONAL MATCH is not very suitable  for the scenario, what I am trying to do is more like first find 305 result, and then adding more into to this 305 result